# ECS CPU/Memory usage container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs

How can I see the used resources per ECS container? Now im able to see the resources from the whole cluster but I want to see it per container.

I know I can see it via `docker stats` when I SSH to my cluster, but I prefer Cloudwatch for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECS doesn't provide per container metrics on CloudWatch.

You could install the [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) in your containers via the Docker file. You can configure CloudWatch agent to publish a bunch of host level metrics.

However, note that all of these metrics would be [Custom Metrics and would cost a lot](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/).

Comment: Thanks! Will look into that, also have seen https://docs.docker.com/config/thirdparty/prometheus/ as a nice alternative.